# How to create a multi sql server authentication user with Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm building an app using Laravel and SQL Server. What I want is to be able to use the Server Authentication Users as the user of my app. For example when a user want to connect to the application his login must be a Server Authentication User that will connect to the database just as it is done in the .env file. How can i so that?
(Sorry  for my bad English)

Comment: is it mobile app?

Comment: no it's a web app

Comment: can you provide code that you tried

Comment: For exemple we have this in the laravel .env file: 
DB_DATABASE=Database_name 
DB_USERNAME=database_username 
DB_PASSWORD=database_userpassword

When a user log in, it should modify the DB_USERNAME and the DB_PASSWORD values in the .env file. What i want to know is: is it possible to have mutiple users connected simultaneously to my application using this method?